How to defer iTerm2 unopened tabs from starting up a shell?
I normally keep dozens of tabs open in several windows in iTerm2 on my Mac. But weeks or months can go by where I won't ever use them, I just keep it all organized in a way that each iTerm window belongs to a context.
The problem is that it takes a lot of time to start iTerm up (my .bashrc is beefy), and they all take a certain amount of system resources away for nothing. During iTerm startup, how can I prevent it from starting up my shell (bash) in all of those (unused) tabs?
Ideally iTerm would/should have a switch somewhere like "Defer shell startup for restored sessions in unused tabs." But I can't find it anywhere, maybe there's a workaround? The idea is that each shell session would only be started once I click on a tab that has a restored session in them or the first tab on the foreground after UI restoration is completed. Naturally, new tabs should all start shells as always (although that could also be a switch maybe).
As a bonus point a "shutdown shell but save session" tab command would be very useful, something that would turn off the shell but keep the scroll buffer and working directories stowed away for later peruse. The "Bury Session" is almost like that, except the shell and processes keep on running while the session is buried.
